# Format Datetime Object of type Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to convert a `DateTime` instance (`DataTime.Now`) in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

The output should remain a `DateTime`, not a `string`. How to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with the `DateTime` as it is? You can easily convert the `DateTime` to like any format you wish to. No need to play around with the way it's stored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. A `DateTime` is a struct containing numerical values, it does not contain any formatting information. That information is stored in the [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specifically the [`DateTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

The information in the `CurrentCulture` is shared across the entire thread, so if you do change that format, it will change for your entire application. If you want to format just that instance, use `ToString` with your appropriate format.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

[`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. You can only have a format with *textual* representation which is `string` representation.

The concept of a format *only* applies when you're converting to a `string`.